# Is there any other method for java scheduler more easier to understand than Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I've created a small java program and I want to launch it everyday at 1 o'clock.
I can add it windows task plannifier and it works very well but I want to do it with java.

The java timer task seems to be not good.

I heard about Quartz and when I try their it seems to be complicated for me or I don't find the simple example or tutorial.

Can anyone know some good tutorial or example code easier than the Quartz's site.
Or redirect me to some other site.

Comment: By the way: The Java Timer is not bad. It's simply not built for what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Quartz and the built in `Timer` class  are not built to *start* your whole application. They are built to run some specified tasks according to some schedule *as long as your application is running*.

To actually *start* your application at a specified time, an external resource will be necessary (unless you want your application to run at all times and only do some activity ever so often).

For that purpose the Windows Task Scheduler is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

### Quartz

[Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is a full-featured, open source job scheduling service that can be integrated with, or used along side virtually any Java EE or Java SE application.

The basic terminology are (at very basic view):

**Scheduler** :   You can think of this as the core container or something that is the base of quartz.

**Job** : You can think this as the task we need to do , out simple java Class

**Trigger** : Something that will make Job to run on scheduler, there are two types of trigger  with quartz

1. Simple Trigger (you can configure it with delay between execution, delay for first execution  . . and many such params)
2. Cron-Trigger : Here you can configure trigger with cron expression.

### Also See

- [Quartz cook book](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/cookbook/index.html)
- [Quartz : Best practices](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/best_practices.html)

Comment: Didn't we have a conversation about single-link answers before? A single link without any further information is a bad answer. It can bit-rot and then your answer becomes useless if someone else has the same question.

Comment: @Joachim `Can anyone know some good tutorial or example code easier than the Quartz's site. Or redirect me to some other site.`

Comment: @Jigar: and you answer that by providing the first third-party link you find when entering "quartz example" in Google? I'm sorry, but that doesn't look terribly useful.

Comment: sorry, is that question for me?

Comment: Sorry i don't remenber about the signle-link or maybe i forgot

Comment: @Joachim agree. added some valuable information that can surely help OP. @user618111 please review updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
small java program and I want to launch it everyday at 1 o'clock
```

1. [cronjob in unix](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

   **Scheduling a Job For a Specific Time Every Day**

The basic usage of `cron` is to execute a job in a specific 
time as shown below.This will execute the `sample_java_program`
everyday at 1am.

```
30 01 * * * java /home/suresh/sample_java_program

    * 30 – 30th Minute
    * 01 – 01 AM
    * * – every Day
    * * – every Month 
    * * – Every day of the week
```

1. [Scheduling in windows](http://www.nerkait.com/blogengine.net/post/2009/03/06/How-to-Schedule-a-Java-Application-from-Windows-Task-Scheduler.aspx)  this link might help u .

Answer (score 0):

[cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/) is another one

Answer (score 0):

When you say:
`Both Quartz and the built in Timer class are not built to start your whole application.`

So i could never launch my whole java program with Quartz or Timer.
it only launches some speicfic task while my prg is running?

so it's better to keep Windows task Scheduler?
ok thank you

Comment: This question should have been a comment on my answer, but I'll answer here anyway: yes, both are designed to start some code *inside* your application. Of course that task could be "run another Java program", but that would require your application to be running at all time (or at least when you want to schedule something).